# Glassfish 4 looses instances of cdi sessionscopeds beans

Tags: jsf, glassfish, cdi, session-scope

The software i was developing worked fine in my development environment (windows, glassfish4, java8, mysql5.7). The problem is putting it on the approval environment (Linux-OpenSuse, glassfish4, java8, mysql5.7) the glassfish looses the instance of session scoped bean already created and create it again. I know it's not much information, but, i really don't know where to start to resolve it. Anyway, each info is welcome.

Comment: when does it loose session information? Always?, sometimes?, when? What else is different in the architecture?

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry i couldn't investigate the problem because of time. We rebuild our linux (opensuse) environment and reconfigured each tool. It worked for me. Thanks everybody who spent time trying to help me. Thanks @Kukeltje